# system.threading Ms build command line error for VS 2012 project

Tags: c#, msbuild

Have a VS 2012 project for which i'm trying to create a build xml for command line build. Inside the VS 2012 the build runs fine, but while running command line build using MSbuild i'm getting an error,

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Tasks' 
does notexist in the namespace 'System.Threading' 
(are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Project is targetting Dot net 4.5 framework which is already installed. The OS is windows 2008 R2 X64. I know the error is regarding the incorrect framework reference but unable to find the cause, as this is working fine inside the VS 2012. Does this have to do with the OS being X64? Can anyone point out where its going wrong? thanks..

Comment: You're sure it's just targeting the normal .NET 4.5 framework? Not some restricted version? Can you post a screenshot of your build properties page?

Comment: Not able to post images just yet...but the project properites says,   Target Framework: .NET Framework 4.5. Its working fine inside VS 2012 but not working in MSbuild cmd mode..do we need to specify anything inside the build.xml ??

Comment: Ah, I'd missed the fact that it's working in Visual Studio. Are you running an old version of MSBuild by any chance?

Comment: Thank you Jon, it was using MSBuild from framework 3.5

Comment: You might want to add an answer then, going into how you checked that and how you fixed it.

Comment: yep done that too..i'm sure there are "Others" :)

Comment: No, you've currently edited this into the *question* - you should add it as an *answer* (ideally with more details).

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

Thanks to Jon Skeet for this , i was using MSBuild from framework 3.5, Adding to this you need to mention Toolsversion attr in the begining of build xml else the aspnet compiler from V2.0 will be used causing error target framework not found